# Вопрос о Кутузове и о морском канате

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, литература

Подскажите, кто знает...
Читая "Войну и мир", всё время спотыкаюсь, когда дохожу до вот этого предложения.

> Он, очевидно, слушал только оттого, что у него были уши, которые, несмотря на то, что в одном из них был **морской канат**, не могли не слышать; но очевидно было, что ничто из того, что мог сказать ему дежурный генерал, не могло не только удивить или заинтересовать его, но что он знал вперед все, что ему скажут, и слушал все это только потому, что надо прослушать, как надо прослушать поющийся молебен.

Что за морской канат, который был в одном ухе Кутузова?

Comment: @irina19, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 7):

КАНАТ, каната, м. 1. Очень толстая веревка и т.д. 2. Смолистая пряжа такой веревки, кусочками к-рой вместо ваты моряки закладывают себе уши (мор.). Он уже заносил руки, чтобы положить в уши канат. Салтыков-Щедрин. (Из Толкового словаря Ушакова)

Из цитаты развёрнутой становится ясно, что имеет в виду автор СТАРОЙ ПОМПАДУРШИ: 
«Но когда доложили, что лошади поданы, когда старый помпадур начал укутываться и уже заносил руки, чтобы положить в уши канат, Надежда Петровна не выдержала. Она быстро сдернула с своих плеч пуховую косынку и, обвернув ею шею помпадура, вскрикнула... От этого крика проснулось эхо соседних лесов.» Положить в уши канат - то же, что заткнуть уши.

Comment: Всё теперь понятно! Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 4):

Здесь Лёв Николаевич напоминает читателю о том, что Кутузов был глуховат на левое ухо.

Answer (score 2):

Забавно: за такую корявую фразу ученику 10-11 класса следует снизить оценку. Верно? )))))

Comment: Вы про фразу Льва Николаевича? Ну это известно, граф легкостью стиля не отличался.

Answer (score 0):

Мое невежество меня самого смущает, однако, перечитывая недавно "Войну и мир", я тоже заинтересовался этим канатом, погуглил и обнаружил обсуждение данного вопроса здесь. На этом я и остановился, решив, что канат - это корявая метафора.
Сегодня, однако, в "Обрыве" Гончарова прочёл, что Райский привез в подарок Титу Никонычу "кусок морского каната класть в уши". Кто бы мог подумать - видимо, имеется в виду действительно канат, и это никакая не метафора - в том числе и у Толстого.